# Read 321 mb csv file efficiently. I have used opencsv to read data from this 321 mb file but it's take a lot time to read and do further operations

Tags: java, csv, large-files, opencsv, processing-efficiency

My job is to get data from CSV between two dates. For this firstly I have loaded all data into a list of beans. Then loop through the list and prepared my result.

The problem is in this process I have to loop through a lot of data.

I want a solution where I will load only necessary data from CSV. Ultimately I want to reduce the operations I am doing.

```
beansExtractedFromCsv = new CsvToBeanBuilder(new FileReader(s3StorageLocation.concat(s3FileName))).withType(CsvExtractTemplate.class).build().parse();
```

In this line, I am parsing all data  from CSV

```
dataWriteOnCSVOrDB(fromTime, toTime, false, beansExtractedFromCsv);
```

Here I am passing all data extracted from CSV to my method, where I am looping through a lot of data to calculate my expected result.

There is another option in OpenCsv to read line by line. I haven't tried that.

Comment: csv's can be read the same as txt files, have you tried that?

Comment: No, 

Ok I am trying this

Comment: Like @Stultuske said but to elaborate a bit, you can use `Stream<String>`, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17866514/1745616 Reading and processing it line by line will cut memory use significantly. Only down-side is if your data contains values with line-breaks (using quotes) then this method might work incorrectly. But if you know your data doesn't contain this then it will work fine.